# (Android) Tabbed layout with multiple dynamical listviews - is it possible using tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I need to do a tabbed layout with dynamically populated listviews inside each tab and I'm unsure which method to use, since *tabActivity* has been deprecated.

Do I absolutely need to use fragments to achieve this correctly? Can't it be done with Tabhost + an activity for each tab? If so, what's the way around not using Tabactivity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TabActivity has been deprecated in favour of fragments as of Android 3.0 (API Level 11) which isn't very popular yet. http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

I say develop your app with tabs.

Comment: With Tabactivity and all? Will that work on newer devices? Thanks